# In Python have a list of tuples and for each tuple would like to put x[0] and x[1] into column A and B of an Excel spreadsheet

Tags: python, excel, list, tuples, xlrd

I used `xlrd` to pull an Excel file with prescription numbers and drug names. I then made a list of tuples that include the prescription number and drug name. The list looks like this:

```
[(123, enalapril), 
 (456, atenolol), 
 (789, lovastatin)
]
```

I would like to create a new Excel file that lists each prescription number in column `A` with the corresponding drug in column `B`. I plan to use `xlsxwriter`. Is there a way to do this with tuples?

A workaround I tried involved creating two separate lists (one of prescription numbers and one of drugs). It worked in this small example, but I would like to make this work reliably on a large scale. I am concerned that by using two separate lists somehow the prescription numbers may be matched to the wrong drug in the new Excel file. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not familar with xlsxwriter, but it seems to accept your data for example as the `data` argument to `add_table` ([docs](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_tables.html)). Are you trying to convert `[(a, b), (c, d), ...]` to something similar to `([a, c, ...], [b, d, ...])` - that is, accessing your data by columns? Maybe you're looking for [`zip(*___)`](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/dd39f9e1f0f2503ddd6ece611bdc37a9)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`xlsxwriter` makes it pretty straight forward to create a basic spreadsheet:

**Code:**

```
import xlsxwriter

# Create a workbook and add a worksheet.
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('my_excel.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# Some data we want to write to the worksheet.
data = [(123, 'enalapril'), (456, 'atenolol'), (789, 'lovastatin')]

# Iterate over the data and write it out row by row.
for row, line in enumerate(data):
    for col, cell in enumerate(line):
        worksheet.write(row, col, cell)

workbook.close()
```

**Results:**

[image]